# how to use TensoFlow SequenceExample proto for time series data?

Tags: tensorflow

I'd like to use TensorFlow SequenceExample proto for time series data (like speech), but how to define "context" and "feature_lists" is not clear to me. For example, with n speech utterances, each utterance has M_n frames (of dim 24), and each frame has its own label. After SequenceExample is created, how to read it is also an issue since utterances have variable length of features.

Comment: Show some working. Something that you have tried.

Comment: I had a similar question spelled out a bit more specifically. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50558268/tensorflow-reading-time-series-data-from-tfrecord